# Immersive limit of embeddings is injective on the interior?

Tags: differential-topology, uniform-convergence, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

$\newcommand{\pl}{\partial}$
$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}$

Let $\M,\N$ be smooth compact, connected, oriented manifolds **of the same dimension**. $\M$ can have a boundary.

Let $\,f_n:\M \to \N$ be a sequence of smooth orientation-preserving **embeddings**, which converges uniformly to a smooth **immersion** $f:\M \to \N$.

Is it true that $f|_{\M^o}$ is injective? ($\M^o$ is the interior of $\M$).